# proof that $n$ is prime or has prime factor $\leq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

apparently my attempt proof is wrong says the chat person will, so can you guys tell me how to fix please :)

> Show that any integer $n \gt 1$ is either a prime or has as a factor a prime $\leq \sqrt{n}$

if $n$ is prime that is that.

if $n$ isn't prime it has prime factors $n=p_1 p_2 \dots p_i$

assume $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_i\gt \sqrt{n}$

then $n=\sqrt{n}$ or $n\lt p_1 p_2 \dots p_i$, contradiction!

so $n$ has a prime factor $\leq \sqrt{n}$

Comment: You need to mention that $i>1$, and omit that silly sentence that $n=\sqrt{n}$, but otherwise this is OK.

Comment: You are assuming ALL of the $p>\sqrt{n}$, that's the problem.

Comment: @AdamHughes but that is one of the wrong possibilities i thought? leading to contradiction cause it is one prime factor and then 2 makes it bigger than n

Comment: @AngeloRendina but the problem is 'a' prime factor, so for contradiction i need all to be bigger than $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: No, you might have just one factor bigger and the others lower.

Comment: That's not a problem @AngeloRendina , that's how you derive the contradiction.

Comment: @beginner no, nowhere in the problem is that a thing. All it says is either $n$ is prime or it has some prime factor $\le \sqrt{n}$. You assume the negation which is that $n$ is composite **and** has all prime factors at least $\sqrt{n}$. Then the conclusion is $n<n$, a contradiction.

Comment: oh i see why it is silly now, cause no prime(from my factors) could make that true, thanks @adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two cases:

1. If $n$ is prime, then we're done
2. If $n$ is not prime, then we have two cases:

   2.1. If $n$ has a prime factor $p\leq\sqrt{n}$, then we're done

   2.2. If $n$ does not have a prime factor $p\leq\sqrt{n}$, then:

   - $n$ has a prime factor $p>\sqrt{n}$
   - $n$ has a factor $\frac{n}{p}\leq\sqrt{n}$
   - If $\frac{n}{p}$ is prime, then we're done
   - If $\frac{n}{p}$ is not prime, then:

     - Let $q$ be a prime factor of $\frac{n}{p}$
     - $q$ is also a prime factor of $n$, and $q<\frac{n}{p}\leq\sqrt{n}$